# Django Model Field Auto-Updates Depending on Related Instances

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I am looking for a solution to being able to automatically update model instances depending on a related model instance.

It seems simple and I've looked everywhere. I'm new to this so let me know I am asking the question incorrectly or thinking about it in the wrong way.

I need Account.monthly_donations to automatically update to the total amount of all of it's related donations in the last 30 days.  Similarly for yearly_donations and lifetime_donations.

I also need Account.is_subscribed to toggle True if

- monthly_donations >= 20, or
- yearly_donations >= 200 or
- lifetime_donations >= 10000

and then back to False if requirements not met.

```
class Account(models.Model):
    ...
    is_subscribed = models.BooleanField(
        default=False
    )
    monthly_donations = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0
    )
    yearly_donations = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0
    )
    lifetime_donations = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0
    )


class Donation(models.Model):
    related_account = models.ForeignKey(
        Account,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='donation'
    )
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()
```

Are signals the solution?  However, I don't want the totals to update only when a new donation is saved.  I need it updated daily based on the donations dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signals wouldn't solve your problem 100%. Because `monthly_donations` and `yearly_donations` depends on the current date to give you the right answer.

Signals are usually a good solution for when multiple parts of your code is interested in the same events (in your case it's just the `Account` instances that are interested in new `Donation` objects). Also when you have no direct access to the code (for example a third-party app, or a built-in model like `User` or `Permission` where you can't modify it).

In your case, you have access to the `Donation` model, so you could perhaps override the `save()` method:

```
class Donation(models.Model):
    # db fields ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # call the actual save method
        update_account_totals()        # execute this code every time the model is saved
```

But, as you already mentioned, you don't want to update this information only when a new donation is created.

Actually, all the information you are currently storing in the `Account` model can be calculated on-the-fly. Using more advanced QuerySet expressions we can do all the work directly in the database. And even though we are going to calculate it every time, it can be pretty fast. Specially if you cache the results.

This kind of query is called [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/). I will write down an example for your use case, using the `annotate()` function. The `annotate()` function is a special function that "adds extra fields" to each instance of the result set, based on the criteria we define.

Usually those fields we add with the `annotate()` are the **sum** of something, or the **count**, or the **average**. In your case, we can list all `Account` objects, and for each object, we can *annotate* with the sum of monthly donations, yearly donations and all time donations. We can even use this calculated field to check if the account is a subscriber or not, using a case/when queries.

It's a little bit more complicated than trivial QuerySets like `filter()`, `all()` that we use all the time, but I took the time to write it down and put some comments that can perhaps help you out.

> PS: The example below uses the new [filtering on annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations) introduced on Django 2.0

**Implementation:**

```
import datetime

from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import Case, When, Q, Value, BooleanField, Sum
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

# first we use the `timedelta` to get refernce points
# considering now = 2018-02-14, `last_month` will be equal to 2018-01-14
# and `last_year` will be equal to 2017-02-14
last_month = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
last_year = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=365)

# here we are building a sub-query using the Sum object, we are going to use it next
# to sum all the donations happened after "2018-01-14", that is, in the last 30 days
monthly_sum_expression = Sum('donation__amount', filter=Q(donation__date__gte=last_month))

# similar to the previous one, we are summing all donations that happened after "2017-02-14"
# that is, one year ago
yearly_sum_expression = Sum('donation__amount', filter=Q(donation__date__gte=last_year))

# here we are not applying any filter, so we will sum *all* donations
all_time_sum_expression = Sum('donation__amount')

# below, we are building the logic to tell if the person is a subscriber or not (based on the criteria you
# entered in your question.. monthly donations >= 20, or yearly donations >= 200, etc)
# The pipe "|" means it's an OR. the "Q" is an object that holds a database expression
# if any of those criteria are met, then it will return "True"
subscriber_condition = When(Q(monthly__gte=20) | Q(yearly__gte=200) | Q(all_time__gte=1000), then=Value(True))
subscriber_expression = Case(subscriber_condition, default=Value(False), output_field=BooleanField())

# now here we build our query. in this case we are selection *all* the accounts and for each account
# we are adding 4 extra fields calculated on the fly: monthly, yearly, all_time, and subscriber_status.
# the Coalesce function is for the cases where the account had no donation in the last 30 days
# instead of returning "None" it will return "0"
accounts = Account.objects.annotate(
    monthly=Coalesce(monthly_sum_expression, Value(0)),
    yearly=Coalesce(yearly_sum_expression, Value(0)),
    all_time=Coalesce(all_time_sum_expression, Value(0)),
    subscriber_status=subscriber_expression
)
```

**Usage:**

```
# then in your code you can use those calculated fields just like you would if it was a regular database field
for account in accounts:
    print(account.monthly)
    print(account.yearly)
    print(account.all_time)
    print(account.subscriber_status)
```

This would be an optimal solution. This way you would be sure the data is *always* up to date. Another solution would be keeping the database fields like you have, and create some [cron jobs](http://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on the server, so they would update every day all your accounts, and your `Account` fields would work as a "cache" of the calculated fields.

Then you could combine the cron jobs with the `save()` method override I mentioned in the beginning.

Comment: Thank you, @vitor.  Also, your blog has been very useful to me in the past!

Where exactly would I implement the aggregation?  As in which directory/file?

Comment: You're welcome! The best place to implement it would be inside a [Model Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#managers). You can write a custom [QuerySet method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#creating-a-manager-with-queryset-methods). That way this query would be accessible like `Account.objects.donations().order_by('all_time')` (the extra fields can be used normally, even for ordering like this).